# How to generate a table of counts with subsets of classifications?

Tags: r

I am trying to do a basic analysis spitting out some counts/frequencies. The dataset I have (sample picture attached) has a unique identifier for each person per row, along with race and ethnicity classifications along with location information (STATE) and information on whether they have or have not taken the test (P_U12VRC). If I am trying to determine how many people (counts) in each race/ethnicity category (1-4) in each state (where each state is labeled as a specific number 1-50) have or have not taken the test (1 or 0), how would I generate a table for this information.  As I have never done this type of analysis taking into account 2 variables when determining a third, I am not sure how it would be visualized. I appreciate any and all help!

```
structure(list(SEQNUMC = c("152651", "12631", "261061", "102261", "269631","247001", "262721", "217211", "191371", "170311", "152311", "110191", "162801", "54921", "104221", "48621"), RACEETHK = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), STATE = c(48L, 26L, 55L, 6L, 12L, 44L, 26L, 24L, 53L, 26L, 22L, 24L, 12L, 5L, 16L, 1L), P_U12VRC = c(1L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: Sample image of dataset]

Comment: Rather than using a "sample picture" use `dput(head(df, nrows))` (changing nrows to some realistic number) and copy the output into a code segment here.

Comment: I'm not sure if that worked, but I followed your instructions and added the output into the original post! Thank you for letting me know that was an option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to count the number of rows. There are **many** packages to do exactly this. Lets assume your data is called `df`

## tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(RACEETHK, STATE, P_U12RC) %>% summarize(n = n())
```

## data.table

```
library(tidyverse)
setDT(df)
df[, .(n = .N), by = .(RACEETHK, STATE, P_U12RC)]
```

## sqldf

```
# setDF(df) #if you tried the data.table first run this line
library(sqldf)
sqldf('
SELECT COUNT(1) as n, RACEETHK, STATE, P_U12RC 
FROM df 
GROUP BY 2, 3, 4')
```